# LINQ to SQL - select query

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I need help. I've some types defined:

```
Class1(){int ID; double Price;}
Class2(){int ID; Class1 myClass1;}
Class3(){int ID; List<Class2> Class2List;}
```

Now I have a list `List<Class3> class3List`, from which I need to take only the min `double` value (the min `Price`). Is this possible to do with LINQ to SQL, or do I need to use `foreach` loop?

Comment: Do you want a minimum of all `Class3` in the list or a minimum for each `Class3` in the list?

Comment: I need min price from Class3List, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var min = class3List.SelectMany(x => x.Class2List).Min(x => x.myClass1.Price);
```

Use `SelectMany` method to flatten your list of lists `List<List<Class2>>` into `List<Class2>`, and then return minimum value in a sequence of prices, fetched by simple selector `x => x.myClass1.Price`.